# Are EC2 instances stable for computation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I use the Amazon EC2 instances(t1.micro, m1.medium) for some method execution, I found that the execution type of a particular method varies very abruptly. For example, when I run 8-Queen solvers, sometimes the average execution time is 43 seconds. Sometimes the average execution time can be 58 seconds and even 70 seconds. What's the problem with that? I've checked that there is only this process running in the virtual machine.

Comment: Do you really think you're running on a dedicated machine with 511 MB or RAM (or whatever it is?) These are virtual machines running along-side many other machines. Performance is going to be highly variable.

Comment: This isn't limited to just AWS either.  Any cloud hosting provider is going to have this to some degree.

Comment: In addition to what @DarkFalcon said, you are making the situation worse by using the small instance sizes where your instance is a very small virtualized fraction of a host machine.  You should also consider using C3 class instances that are compute optimized if your use case is CPU bound.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not. If you need predictable performances go with "dedicated instances": http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/dedicated-instances/.